# Unable to find the Hardcoded web controls added inside an AjaxTabContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working on dynamic generation of WebControls. I Have a Ajax TabContainer with a TabPanel inside it. The TabPanel contains a ContentTemplate. Inside the ContentTemplate is a Asp:Panel.

'**Current Issue: I am trying to add my dynamically generated web controls inside the Asp:Panel present inside the ContentTemplate. But i couldn't add the dynamic controls directly and also couldn't find the Panel as it is always null and Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object Exception occurs.'**

How to solve this issue?

My aspx Code:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" Width ="1178px" VerticalStripWidth="1000px" OnDemand="false" ScrollBars="Vertical" ActiveTabIndex="1" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true">
       <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat ="server">    
          <HeaderTemplate> Upload</HeaderTemplate>
              <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:Panel ID ="Panel1" runat="server">
                  </asp:Panel>
              </ContentTemplate>       
       </asp:TabPanel>         
    </asp:TabContainer>
```

My C# code:

```
protected void findpanel()
    {
        Panel Panel1= TabContainer1.FindControl("TabPanel1").FindControl("Panel1") as Panel;
        //Alwals Null
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "TB1";
        tb.Text = "Hi";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
        //Object reference not set to an instance of an oject         
    }

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        findpanel();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new Panel and put into inside the ContentTemplate of your

```
var newPanel = new Panel();
TabPanel1.ContentTemplate.Controls.Add(newPanel);
```

Comment: @ Robert Chumley: MyTabPanel.ContentTemplate.Controls Intellissense doesnt work. Are you sure ?